# Does randsample function exit in Julia?

Tags: julia

would you mind if I asked, is there any function like `randsample` in Julia?
`sample` function is in Julia. Is it same to `randsample` in matlab?? What is difference between `sample` and `rand` in Julia?

Tanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rand` is defined in Base. It supports unweighted sampling with replacement. You can sample from the set of values (there is a broad range what that set can be, for instance if you use Distributions.jl you can sample from a wide array of distributions defined there; by default `rand()` samples from a uniform distribution on [0,1[ inverval).

`sample` is defined in the StatsBase.jl package. It supports sampling from a population with or without replacement, that is optionally weighted.

**EDIT**

A simple example of sampling without replacement:

```
julia> using StatsBase

julia> sample(1:5, 4, replace=false)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
 3
 1
 2

julia> sample(1:5, 5, replace=false)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 4
 2
 5
 1

julia> sample(1:5, 6, replace=false)
ERROR: Cannot draw more samples without replacement.
```

Comment: could you please help me?How can I use sample without replacement .

Comment: I have added a simple example in the answer.